# How to track Unique URL once in Goal Conversion, Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, conversion-tracking

In Google Analytics, a Unique URL for a Thank you page visited by a person can trigger multiple goal completions.

For example:

If a person purchases and is sent to /order/900001/thank-you.html he can save that URL and then visit it in the future for whatever reason.

If he does so in another "unique session", it counts as another goal conversion, because it matches the goal completion URL regex. However it is NOT another conversion, and we know that because it is the thank you page for an order that was already counted (Order 900001).

Is it possible to limit Goal Conversions to count only ONCE per exact URL?

And if it is not possible, what would be the best work around for this?

I already thought about making the thank you page have a different URL if a person tries to access it later (e.g. /order/900001.html) but am wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Make your links expire so that if a user bookmarks the link they won't be able to visit it again.

Comment: How exactly do you "Expire" a link? If you mean a redirect URL kind of thing, a person can still get the final url from the address bar and so it not fool proof.

Comment: I bought a product that does this for me but if you know how to do it than you would save $$. Search for "expire download links" in Google and you will be able to find products and blogposts on how to do it